# Onesignal flutter Cannot receive notifications in background

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, onesignal

- `setNotificationOpenedHandler` works pretty fine when the app is running.
- And I'm able to receive notifications in foreground. I have handle the notification reception with `setNotificationWillShowInForegroundHandler`.

#### But when the app is terminated, I don't receive any notification.

- My users are not in touch with some crucial that affect them.
- Just like `setNotificationWillShowInForegroundHandler`, Is there any method like `setNotificationWillShowInBackgroundHandler` ?

#### Or is there any way to handle background notifications in flutter ?